# Rails Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-4

Hey Bootstrap is not working on my rails app (Rails 5.0.5). I followed this steps https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem. Here are my files:

```
//= require reset
//= require_self
//= require_tree . 
@import "bootstrap";
```

application.scss

```
//= require jquery
//= require tether
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

application.js

```
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha6'
gem 'sprockets', '~> 3.0'
```

Gemfile (I exec bundle install after)

Comment: BTW may be you should try  Gem version 4.0.0.beta - it's more recent

Answer (score 0):

> Then, remove all the *= require and *= require_tree statements from the Sass file. Instead, use @import to import Sass files.
>
> Do not use *= require in Sass or your other stylesheets will not be able to access the Bootstrap mixins and variables.
>
> Bootstrap JavaScript depends on jQuery. If you're using Rails 5.1+, add the jquery-rails gem to your Gemfile:
>
> gem 'jquery-rails'

application.scss

```
@import "reset";
@import "bootstrap";
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require tether
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks

gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha6'
gem 'sprockets', '~> 3.0'
```

Restart the server
Check with f12 that you have the assets in your pipeline
[image]

Easy solution. If you do not have the files, just head to [bootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/), download the files, copy the `css` and `js` files to your `/vendor/assets/stylesheets` and `/vendor/assets/javascripts`, then include them in your `application.js` and `scss` with the `@import` statement.

try to precompile your assets with `rails assets:precompile`

Comment: @PoloD.Vargas I think you lost your manifest file `application.js` and `application.scss`. so you will need to first update your post with the following output of your rails console `Rails.application.config.assets.paths`, so that I can read it. then as you do not have the `manifest` files in the asset pipeline include at the bottom of `config/initializers/assets.rb` file the following line `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( application.js )` and `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( application.scss )`, then run `rails assets:precompile`

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up Sprockets require syntax, and Sass' importing. To maintain what you've done before, you'd include bootstrap by using

```
//= require reset
//= require bootstrap
//= require_self
//= require_tree .
```

and

```
//= require jquery
//= require tether
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the problem updating my rails version and following the next guide. 
Hope it helps someone, it was very easy only few steps got it working.
https://www.railstutorial.org/book/filling_in_the_layout#sec-custom_css